# How can I create a dictionary from a data frame with multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to create a dict from a data frame of a stock. The dict keys should be the sector and the values the corresponding tickers.

```
df.set_index('Sector').to_dict()['Ticker']
```

I have this code which works in creating some of the dictionary. The issue being it has created the right amount of keys but only one ticker to each key. I can see from the data frame that most keys should include many more tickers.

The DataFrame looks like this:

| Company | Ticker | Exchange | Sector | Date added | Weighting |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3M | MMM | NYSE | indus | 09/08/76 | 3.022 |

the desired output will be

```
{Indus: MMM, BA, ...., 
 Financials: AXP, GS,...}
```

for all the industry's and tickers

Comment: Please provide a sample dataframe.

Comment: Also, a desired output is needed

Comment: I've updated the post, hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Not completely sure what you want, but I assume you want to group the sectors and create a list of Tickers for each sector. I created an example dataframe as yours is not containing enough rows. Following would be the code to create the dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Sector':['s1', 's1','s1','s2','s2'],
              'Ticker': ['t1','t2','t3','t4','t5'],
              'Other column':[1,2,3,4,5]
                  })

print(df)

result = df.groupby('Sector')['Ticker'].apply(list).to_dict()
print(result)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
  Sector Ticker  Other column
0     s1     t1             1
1     s1     t2             2
2     s1     t3             3
3     s2     t4             4
4     s2     t5             5
```

Dictionary looks like this:

```
{'s1': ['t1', 't2', 't3'], 's2': ['t4', 't5']}
```